# Some kind of short circuit or bad connection maybe

Tags: pontiac, power, grand-am

I have a 00 grand am.  Every time I start my car my time is on 12 but my stations are still set.  What could this be?

Comment: Is this an aftermarket radio, or the factory original?  Has it ever worked since you've had the car?

Comment: Yes factory radio and yes it has always worked.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate power circuits that go to the radio.  One is always on and keeps the clock going and any other temporary settings.  Your preset stations are stored in permanent memory so the battery can be disconnected for vehicle service without you having to reset them all.  The other power circuit comes on when you turn the car key to power the rest of the radio and speakers.

These two circuits will be protected by two different fuses.  If you trust the pictures on [this website](http://www.autogenius.info/pontiac-grand-am-2000-fuse-box-diagram/), the fuse you want to check is in the passenger side fuse box.  The one labeled FUSE BATT should be the one that provides constant battery power to the radio.  Sorry, but I can't speak to the accuracy of those particular diagrams.

That said, a fuse is not the only place a circuit can fail.  The radio could be internally damaged, and the wire for that battery connection could be broken somewhere.  Checking the fuse is the easiest thing to do.